# when setState callback invoke in react 16

Tags: reactjs

[announce react 16 release blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html)

this blog says

> setState callbacks (second argument) now fire immediately after componentDidMount / componentDidUpdate instead of after all components have rendered.

so callback invoked after `componentDidMount`, and parent's `componentDidMount` is invoked after its children's. so I think, in current render tree, it is also after all components have rendered.

what is the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that, right now, (react < 16) `componentDidMount` would fire for a parent component only after all child components have fired their `componentDidMount`.

In react 16, the parent component mount is not dependent on the child components mount.